# Calling to to another page with AJAX while showing loading image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP that gets parameters with post and at the end of the process redirects the user to another page.

Because the whole process can take up to 6 seconds, I wanted to add a loading GIF.
I've created another page that shows the image and calls the first page using AJAX.

No matter what I've tried, I am not able to make the whole process work.
At the end I get ***XMLHttpRequest cannot load Error - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.***

This is the code of the page that calls the PHP process file:

```
<?php

function generateData(){
    global $dpost;
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $dpost .= ',' . $key . ':"' .  $value . '"';
    }
    $dpost .= ',resultType:"pre"';
    $dpost = '{' . substr($dpost, 1) . '}';
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php generateData(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        console.log('1');
        var text='';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'f-api.php',
            type: 'post',
            headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'},
            crossDomain : true,
            content_type: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: <?php global $dpost; echo $dpost; ?>,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('OK')
                alert(text);
                $('.my_update_panel').html(data);
                $('#loading_spinner').hide();
            },
           error: function(data) {
               console.log('Error : ' + data);
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                console.log('Before');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <img src="img/loading-ls.gif">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code inside the process PHP file that redirect to the end url :

```
        logger($lfn, 'DEBUG', 'Redirecting to ' . $url, $email);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;');
    header("Location: " . $url);
    die();
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Or maybe another what to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Comment: The page that i'm calling, f-api.php is the destination of a form action. The target page that I redirect to from f-api.php is changing by the form values. I don't think I can do this with your suggestion.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion. Do you test your local stuff in Chrome?

Comment: @KRONWALLED - Yes.

Comment: Could you try to run it on port 80 so you can visit your local copy with `http://localhost` instead of supplying a port. See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) or just start Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag but don't use it outside of testing! It is a massive vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

This is an issue that basically says that it's not allowing incoming requests to the page, and can be fixed by adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Alternatively, to your `.php` file that you're sending data to:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Comment: I've add and still same result : `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
        header("Location: " . $url);`

Comment: @DovevGolan did you put that code at the TOP of your `.php` file (right after `<?php`)?

Comment: Yes @Ben, I've tried it as well. Still same result.